# Entity Framework Core 8 : mapping a complex namespace of types (non-interface reference type error)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have the following namespace of types I want to map in EF Core 8:

[image]

I know so far that I can't map the interfaces directly. But how can I map the relations to EF Core?

I tried the following (limited subset):

```
public DbSet<AasCore.Aas3_0.Key> KeyDbSets { get; set; }
public DbSet<AasCore.Aas3_0.Reference> ReferenceDbSets { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //modelBuilder.Entity<Extension>().Property(e => e.SemanticId).HasConversion<Reference>(v => (Reference)v, v => (IReference)v);
    //.HasConversion(v => (Reference)v, v => (IReference)v);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Key>().HasKey(b => b.Value);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Reference>().HasMany(r => r.Keys);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Reference>().HasOne(r => (Reference)r.ReferredSemanticId);
}

protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    configurationBuilder
        .Properties<List<IReference>>()
        .HaveConversion<ReferenceInterfaceListConverter>();
    configurationBuilder
        .Properties<List<IKey>>()
        .HaveConversion<KeyInterfaceListConverter>();
}

public class ReferenceInterfaceListConverter : ValueConverter<List<IReference>, List<Reference>>
{
    public ReferenceInterfaceListConverter()
        : base(
            v => v.Cast<Reference>().ToList(),
            v => v.Cast<IReference>().ToList())
    {
    }
}

public class KeyInterfaceListConverter : ValueConverter<List<IKey>, List<Key>>
{
    public KeyInterfaceListConverter()
        : base(
            v => v.Cast<Key>().ToList(),
            v => v.Cast<IKey>().ToList())
    {
    }
}
```

Definitions for key class & interface:

```
public interface IKey : IClass
{
    public KeyTypes Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Key : IKey
{
    public KeyTypes Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IClass> DescendOnce()
    {
        // No descendable properties
        yield break;
    }
    public IEnumerable<IClass> Descend()
    {
        // No descendable properties
        yield break;
    }

    public void Accept(Visitation.IVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.VisitKey(this);
    }

    public void Accept<TContext>(
        Visitation.IVisitorWithContext<TContext> visitor,
        TContext context)
    {
        visitor.VisitKey(this, context);
    }

    public T Transform<T>(Visitation.ITransformer<T> transformer)
    {
        return transformer.TransformKey(this);
    }

    public T Transform<TContext, T>(
        Visitation.ITransformerWithContext<TContext, T> transformer,
        TContext context)
    {
        return transformer.TransformKey(this, context);
    }

    public Key(KeyTypes type, string value)
    {
        Type = type;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Definition for `IReference`:

```
public class Reference : IReference
{
    public ReferenceTypes Type { get; set; }
    public IReference? ReferredSemanticId { get; set; }

    public List<IKey> Keys { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<IClass> DescendOnce()
    {
        if (ReferredSemanticId != null)
        {
            yield return ReferredSemanticId;
        }

        foreach (var anItem in Keys)
        {
            yield return anItem;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<IClass> Descend()
    {
        if (ReferredSemanticId != null)
        {
            yield return ReferredSemanticId;

            // Recurse
            foreach (var anItem in ReferredSemanticId.Descend())
            {
                yield return anItem;
            }
        }

        foreach (var anItem in Keys)
        {
            yield return anItem;

            // Recurse
            foreach (var anotherItem in anItem.Descend())
            {
                yield return anotherItem;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Accept(Visitation.IVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.VisitReference(this);
    }

    public void Accept<TContext>(
        Visitation.IVisitorWithContext<TContext> visitor,
        TContext context)
    {
        visitor.VisitReference(this, context);
    }

    public T Transform<T>(Visitation.ITransformer<T> transformer)
    {
        return transformer.TransformReference(this);
    }

    public T Transform<TContext, T>(
        Visitation.ITransformerWithContext<TContext, T> transformer,
        TContext context)
    {
        return transformer.TransformReference(this, context);
    }

    public Reference(
        ReferenceTypes type,
        List<IKey> keys,
        IReference? referredSemanticId = null)
    {
        Type = type;
        Keys = keys;
        ReferredSemanticId = referredSemanticId;
    }
}
```

The result is the following error:

> Unhandled exception: System.AggregateException: One or `more` errors occurred. `(`The specified `type` `'AasCore.Aas3_0.IKey'` must be a non-interface reference `type` to be used as an entity type.``)

How can I map these classes and interfaces correctly? Added problem is that I can't modify the definitions of the classes/ interfaces

Comment: *I know so far that I can't map the interfaces directly* -- Not indirectly either. `List<IKey> Keys` is impossible.

Comment: So no chance to ever map this completely in EF8?

Comment: No, you aways have to map concrete types.  Remember that the EF class model is nothing more than a modest collection of classes that are part of a data access layer, *not* a domain model. The classes map to database tables and there's no need to change their implementation. Any behavioral diversity should be coded in behavioral patterns based on composition or by mapping the data classes to a domain model with various interfaces.

Comment: Interface support is a [recurring topic on EF's github site](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/1047).

Comment: @GertArnold how would I than map the `Reference` class from above in EF? It is the concrete class but includes an Interface Property. I allways failed on the above error.

Comment: As I said, `List<IKey> Keys` is impossible.